# Homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow H$, $\phi$ surjective, $\exists a \in H : |a| = 5$, show $\exists x \in G : |x| = 5$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow H$, $\phi$ surjective, $\exists a \in H : |a| = 5$, show $\exists x \in G : |x| = 5$, where $|G|$ is finite.

I'm not sure if this proof is correct, but here's what I have so far:

By the First Isomorphism Theorem: $G/\ker\phi$ isomorphic to $\phi(G)$. 
We know $\phi(e_G) = e_H$, so $e_G \in \ker\phi$. 
So that means $\exists ge_G \in G/\ker\phi$ with a bijection mapping to the element of order $5$ in $H$, so that means $|ge_G| = 5 = |g|$ for some $g \in G$.

Notice, I did not use the fact that $\phi$ is surjective, meaning there's most likely something wrong with the proof.

Comment: And what are $G$, $H$, if you don't mind?

Comment: $G, H$ are arbitrary groups

Comment: @ajotatxe but even if $\phi$ wasn't surjective, $ge_G$ would still exist. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You have to use that $\phi$ is surjective. Consider, otherwise, $G=\Bbb Z_3$ and $H=\Bbb Z_{15}$ with $\phi(a)=5a$. No element of order $5$ is hit by $\phi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $ge_G\in G/\ker\phi$ because the elements of $G/\ker\phi$ are the cosets of the subgroup $\ker\phi$ in $G$. So for example $g+\ker\phi\in G/\ker\phi$.

Also note that you *did* use the fact that $\phi$ is surjective, when you take an element of $G/\ker\phi$ that maps to the element of order $5$ in $H$; such an element exists *because* $\phi$ is surjective.

But instead of looking at the quotient, consider the preimage of the element $a\in H$ with $|a|=5$. What can you say about its order?

Comment: Since $\phi$ is surjective, $\exists x \in G$ such that $\phi(x) = a$. But is this sufficient enough to say that $|x| = 5$?

Comment: No it is not. But what *can* you say about $|x|$, knowing that $a^5=e_H$?

Comment: We know $|\phi(x)| | |x|$ so $|x| = 5n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes that's exactly right! So now can you find an element $y\in G$ with $|y|=5$?

Comment: We've shown that every element of $G$ has an order of a multiple of 5, but I still don't see how there's an element of exactly an order of 5. Does it have to do with the fact that $|G|$ is finite?

Comment: No, you haven't shown that every element of $G$ has an order of  multiple of $5$, only elements of $G$ that map to $a$. And to answer your question; if $|x|=5n$ then $|x^n|=5$.